# .htaccess rewrite URL not showing correctly?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I want it so when I write the following:

`http://boundsblazer.com/user/joe`

it internally processes the page:

`http://boundsblazer.com/user/profile?usr=joe`

But keeps the old URL.
However, when I write:

`http://boundsblazer.com/user/joe`

the URL becomes:

`http://boundsblazer.com/user/profile?usr=joe`

I have searched countless threads, and nobody is having the trouble I am. The problem is that when I write my URL, the URL changes and makes it look ugly. This is my **.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://boundsblazer.com/user/profile.php?usr=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /user/profile.php?usr=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The issue is that you are using an absolute URL, instead of a relative URL, and mod_rewrite is performing a redirect instead of a rewrite.