# htaccess short url

Tags: mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess rewrite URL not showing correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594579/htaccess-rewrite-url-not-showing-correctly)

Im trying to hide dynamic php in my url with htaccess, now im a total beginner with htaccess and from what I learned so far I managed to do this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home/$ http://www.something.com/index.php?p=home [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ http://www.something.com/index.php?p=home [NC,L]
```

now what happens is when i write lets say:

www.something.com/home

OR

www.something.com/home/

im redirected to http://www.something.com/index.php?p=home BUT what i want to happen as well is the url to be seen as www.something.com/home, not to show the full path to the user, can some one please tell me what im doing wrong?

thanks in advance :))

Comment: If you write a full URL as replacement pattern, this is what happens. Apache assumes you wanted a redirect, not a local/internal rewrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write a full url in a rewrite rule - apache will perform a redirect (since it's not possible to transparently rewrite a requests to a different server - even if the full url corresponds to the current server).

### Simplest solution

For the example in the question you can simply remove the domain name from the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php?p=home [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will match the urls `/home` or `/home/` and rewrite them to `/index.php?p=home`

### Handle any url

A more flexible idea would be to rewrite all urls e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which will rewrite whatever the current url is as the get argument "p".

A complete example such that it won't rewrite requests for real files (/css/foo.css or any other asset):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### The purpose of the QSA flag

The [`qsa`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) flag, used in both examples, merges any existing get arguments with the new `p` get arg that is being rewritten. so that e.g.

```
 /foo?bar=zum
```

becomes

```
/index.php?p=/foo&bar=zum
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much that worked, but for some weird reason this totally screwed up the style of my website, why did this happen?

Comment: @durian depends how you are referencing your css files - if you use `<link .. href="css/style.css"` that's going to break if the url ends with a `/` - use absolute urls e.g. `<link .. href="/css/style.css"` - Look at the url that your browser is requesting if that's not the reason

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you put full url. try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php?p=home [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?p=home [NC,L]
```