# How to manipulate URL with .htaccess for PHP?

Tags: .htaccess, web, server

My goal is to manipulate the URL bar, so it would be simpler for users.

Im using htaccess and want to manipulate a URL

Current URL is: `localhost/test/htdocs/invite?code=AB2A`

I want the URL to be: `localhost/test/htdocs/invite/ABAC`

How could I use htaccess to accomplish this? I want the user to be able to type in `localhost/test/htdocs/invite/ABAC` and for it to work with my code, because currently they have to write `localhost/test/htdocs/invite?code=AB2A`

I am currently using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)code=([^.?]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^test/htdocs/invite\.php$ /test/htdocs/invite/([^.?]+)? [L,R=301]
```

However, it says 404 Not Found

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594579/htaccess-rewrite-url-not-showing-correctly)

Comment: My URL is http://localhost/test/htdocs/invite?code=1

```RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^invite/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /invite?code=$1 [L,QSA]```

But this does not work

Comment: Please make sure your RewriteEngine is enabled by Apache. To check this, just insert a random string in `.htaccess` file (now save the file), and you must see an error after reloading the page. If there is no error then it means your RewriteEngine is disabled that's why .htaccess is not working

Comment: my rewrite engine works. I just dont know if this exact code is right ? because it has no effect on the URL. Also, at bottom of htacces im removing .php but that shouldnt affect this?

Comment: Your current URL is :`invite?code=AB2A` but why **ABAC** is in modified URL ?

Comment: It is a code, which should be a character anything from A-Z and 0-9

Comment: You say the path of your current URL is `test/htdocs/invite`, but your RewriteRule tries to match `^test/htdocs/invite\.php$`

Answer (score 0):

I used here `\w` which is a word character [0-9A-Za-z].

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^/invite([\w]+)/?$ invite?code=$1
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
      RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: My URL Does not change to /invite/1. It stays as /invite?code=1

Comment: I tried with my solution here in my machine, it is working perfectly for `/invite/1`.